# Проверка вида матрицы: верхнетреугольная или нижнетреугольная

Tags: c#

Что-то тут не так, проверка:

```
public string Vid()
{
    string s;
    bool vt = true; bool nt = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (array[i, j] != 0)
            {
                vt = false;
            }
            if (array[j, i] != 0)
            {
                nt = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (vt == true)
        return s = "верхнетреуголная";
    if (nt == true)
        return s = "нижнетреугольная";
    return s="не является нижневерхнетреугольной";
}
```

Comment: Печально все это. Если определитель равен произведению элементов главной диагонали матрица треугольная. Если при этом произвольный элемент ниже главной диагонали равен нулю матрица верхнетреугольная, если произвольный верхний элемент равен нулю матрица нижнетреугольная. Хотя можно конечно и в цикле нули проверять.

Answer (score 1):

Мрак и ужас.

1. Не проверяются последний столбец/строка (условие i < n - 1)?
2. (странный стиль) (vt == true). Почему не просто (vt)
3. Если ненулевые значения только на гл. диагонали (а то и вся матрица нулевая), то матрица будет "верхнетреугольная"...
4. Вместо if'ов можно было просто использовать операцию "и"...